# How to build ROS noetic and a ros package using Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, ros

I want to build ROS noetic using Dockefile and inside the Docker container, I want to build a package with the same Dockerfile.
Here is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Alok018/Jenkins/blob/master/Dockerfile) which one I am using for building ROS noetic. If you have any suggestion please give me feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually ros container images already in place for docker. You can install the noetic one with `docker pull ros:noetic-robot`. There's also some helpful documentation for using docker with ros [on the wiki](https://wiki.ros.org/docker/)